# Angular - hyperlink blocked by content-security-policy

Tags: angular, content-security-policy, unsafe-inline

I have an angular application, where the routes are defined in the left navigation bar as follows:

```
<li routerLink="/dashboard/dashboard-landing" id="home" routerLinkActive="active">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><em class="cc-nav-icon fas fa-home"></em><span>Home</span></a>
</li>
```

Without the `javascript:void(0)`, the page will make a full load when executing a route, resulting in the angular application to initialize.

Then I have also set the CSP for the application with `script-src 'self';`

Now when I navigate between pages, I get the console error about the CSP validation, because there's a Javascript code inline that tries to execute. I tried the following alternative, but still the CSP violation is there.

`<a href="#" onClick="return false;">`

I know this would work if I add `unsafe-inline` but that sort of beats the point of adding CSP. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Why not put the `routerLink` and `routerLinkActive` on the `a` element? You don't need the `href` attribute.

Comment: I think that's more to do with how the UI is formed - with the theming and icons etc...

Comment: @MikeS. As you suggested, we got around by removing the hyperlink and doing some styling changes inside the list element. Thank you!